# Failed to convert excel to pdf using documents4j

Tags: documents4j

i'm trying to convert an excel file to pdf using documents4j.
when trying to do so i'm getting the following error:

[image]

this is the code i'm running:

[image]

can anyone please tell me why do i get the VB exception and how to overcome it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is in a folder `C:\pdf\newPDF.pdf` but you are not escaping the second backslash properly. You are instead adding a newline character: `\n`. You can already tell by the formatting.

Ideally - when I find the time - I will better validate the input at some point.